# How to use functions when their types are erased?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, dynamic-cast

I need to pass function through interface that erases types like actor's `receive` method. So I'd like to store erased type parameters and use it to cast arguments.

```
class Store[R,T](val action : R => T)(implicit i : TypeTag[R], o : TypeTag[T]) {
  val in : Type = i.tpe
  val out : Type = o.tpe
}
object Store {
  type Any = Store[_,_]
  def apply[R,T](action : R => T)(implicit i : TypeTag[R], o : TypeTag[T]) : Store[R,T] = new Store(action)
}

final case class Box[T](unbox : T)

def getType[T](x : T)(implicit t : TypeTag[T]) : Type = t.tpe

val source = Box("test")

val x = Store[Box[String], Box[Int]](s => Box(s.unbox.length))
val y = Store[Box[Int], Box[Boolean]](i => Box(i.unbox % 3 == 0))

val all : List[Store.Any] = List(x,y)
val a0 = all(0)
val a1 = all(1)
```

I'd like to chain stored actions like that:

```
val c0 = a0.action(source)
val c1 = a1.action(c0)
```

Obviously fails:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : source.type (with underlying type Box[String])
 required: _$1
  val c0 = a0.action(source)
                     ^
one error found
```

I could check that all types matches at the runtime:

```
assert(getType(source) <:< a0.in)
assert(a0.out <:< a1.in)
```

But how could I actually convert arguments to appropriate types? `asInstanceOf` requires compile-time type, not a runtime reflection. What other tricks are available?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use `ClassTag[T]` and its `unapply` method:

```
def castIfPossible[T](object: Any)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] =
  tag.unapply(object)
```

If `object` is of type `T` you recieve `Some[T]` value, otherwise you'll recieve `None`.

Then the thing you'd need to do in your code would be to either assume that types are always matching (but then you wouldn't need reflection probably) or use some `map` or `flatMap` for combining values together.

Personally, I would try to figure out if I could do away withour reflection at all, as if T will be parametrized then reflection won't check if those parameters matches. Then I would use something like type classes for dealing with the problem. But, I understand that it might not always be possible.

Comment: `ClassTag[T]` requires to keep type `T`. >either assume that types are always matching< - that is not problem, I could always assert it as I had shown above. >type classes< but they are useless in runtime when all types are lost. If you need to pass object to interface that accepts `Any` type, than all you could do is runtime pattern matching

Comment: At some point, you are knowing the type of `T` - this is when you can create the `ClassTag` and pass it to the part of code that forgets it - unless you really have no control over objects before you access them and the type is already lost.

As for keeping the type `T` - not necessarily. At some point you might start using existential types. Then T can be known inside `class SomeTHandler[T](value: T)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T])` but horgot on the interface level: `SomeHanlderT[_]`.

Comment: And how could you guess that `SomeHandlerT[_]` should return `Option[T]` when the type is already erased?